# How to prevent music from playing when I connect my iPhone to my car?

Tags: iphone, ios, music, music.app, car-integration

Whenever I connect my iPhone to my car via cable, it starts the music player and always on the very same content. If I use siri, as soon as it's done, music will also start even if it wasn't playing before.

I can't stand the first chords of the first music on that playlist anymore. I tried to look for options to prevent this but could not find any.

Comment: Are you using CarPlay What kind of cable are you using to connect? 3.5mm audio cable? Lightning to USB?

Comment: @IconDaemon Lightning USB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish I had a better answer, but I put a song that always is first in my album to ensure I get an hour of silence when this happens.

Some artists have even uploaded songs that you can add or buy for this.

- https://music.apple.com/us/album/a-a-a-a-a-very-good-song-silent-track/1268932999?i=1268933000

Since your car has to be able to start playing it’s apparently hard for Apple to decide which command to not obey.

I’m not holding my breath for automakers to fix their side of the implementation as well. You’d think Apple could program this to at least shuffle some random song, but so far, you have to take action and make as much silence as Apple has provided on an actual “fix” for this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have a Shortcut Automation enabled. You can verify this by going to the **Shortcuts** app and selecting the **Automation** at the bottom. In the **Personal** section, see if there is an automation labeled "When CarPlay connects". Tap on it, then the next window should look something like this:

[image: Screenshot of the 'When CarPlay connects' automation]

In the **Do** section, you will see **Play Music**; tap on it. The next window will give you the opportunity to select the playlist that you would like to listen to.

Now in the **Music** app, you should have a playlist of the particular music you are interested in.

#### How do you get it to stop playing the same content over and over again?

This is where you have to get creative with the playlist inside of the **Music** app. What I will do is create a **Smart Playlist** of whatever artist, genre, etc. I want for that playlist. In the options for the Smart Playlist, check the "Limit to ..." option.

[image: Screenshot of the Smart Playlist options window]

Select the number of items, hours, minutes, etc. then after "selected by" choose **least often played**. This will check the play count for songs that fit the criteria of the top section of this window. As in the screenshot, it will only select 100 of the least played songs by the "Artist" that contains whatever string you provide.

I'm not really sure about the issue you are having with Siri, but hopefully this gives you another option so as not to have to listen to the same chords repeatedly.