# Don't auto-start music on iPhone/car when audio ends

Tags: iphone, audio, music.app, car-integration

I connect my iPhone to my car's stereo system via a Lightning-to-USB adaptor.  If I listen to something that plays audio (e.g., Youtube), then as soon as the audio ends, the Music app immediately starts playing music.  Specifically, it starts playing from some kind of auto-generated playlist that contains all songs on my device, in alphabetical order, by song title.  (This happens even if I had been previously playing some album in the Music app and paused it; it doesn't resume its previous playback, but switches to the all-songs playlist.)

I find this annoying.  I would like to have silence after the audio stops.  Is there a way that I can change this behavior, to not auto-play music the moment something else stops playing audio?

Answer (score 4):

I think this might be due to the vehicle you're driving - it would be useful to know what you're driving. There might be a setting for it.

If there isn't an option to fix this,  a cheap hack is to buy this song for ten minutes of silence, which would give you plenty of time to manually stop it or choose something else: https://music.apple.com/us/album/a-a-a-a-a-very-good-song-silent-track/1268932999

Comment: I rearranged your words since it’s actually more of an answer than a comment (hacks and workarounds count as an answer).  Feel free to rollback or edit as necessary.

Comment: If you don't ever play music from your phone, you can uninstall the music app off your phone, and then it won't play.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be a good Apple solve for this as it's kind of engineered into how the iPod audio works on the original iPhones and iPods.

It would be great if [CarPlay could signal to the device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/423172/5472) it's not needed to fall back on the old - [connect a device and play the alphabetically first song in the library](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/448034/5472) functionality.

The vehicle is responsible for not asking for a song in all the cases I've encountered - can you check with the [operations manual / vendor of the car to be sure there's no way for you to disable auto play when a device is connected](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/444331/5472)?